# plus operator for set iterator doesn't work

Tags: c++

this works fine, but seems rather ugly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <set>

int main ()
{
    std::set<int> v;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        v.insert(i);
    }
    for(std::set<int>::iterator it1 = v.begin(); it1!=v.end(); ++it1)
    {
        std::set<int>::iterator it2=it1;
        std::advance(it2,1);
        for(; it2!=v.end(); ++it2)
        {
           std::cout<<*it1<<" "<<*it2<<std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this doesn't compile because set::iterator doesn't have + operator, why is that? is there an elegant way around this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <set>

int main ()
{
    std::set<int> v;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        v.insert(i);
    }
    for(std::set<int>::iterator it1 = v.begin(); it1!=v.end(); ++it1)
    {
        for(std::set<int>::iterator it2=it1+1; it2!=v.end(); ++it2)
        {
        std::cout<<*it1<<" "<<*it2<<std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried with the iterator.next()

Comment: Have you tried `std::advance` or `std::distance`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews He obviously did - it's in the question.

Comment: Depends on your sense of elegance, but I see nothing wrong with: `for(std::set<int>::iterator it2=it1; ++it2!=v.end();)` (in your second snippet). You wouldn't normally write a loop like that but in this case you definitely know that `it1 != v.end()`.

Comment: @rici I'd rather use @Nihar's idea `for(std::set<int>::iterator it2=std::next(it1,1); it2!=v.end(); it2++)` seems a little more readable

Comment: As @Nihar probably meant, C++11 provides `std::next` that does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`std::set`'s iterators are [bidirectional iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), because internally sets are node-base structures. Applying an offset with `+` would be O(N) for this kind of structure, so its iterators don't directly support that. This operation is supported for random access iterators, for which it is O(1).

Comment: This seems to miss the point. Why does having O(N) complexity makes impossible to have an operator overload?

Comment: probably because most people expect a + operator to work in O(1), or?

Comment: @titus Right. The standard library doesn't like to support expensive operations. If you really want to increment a bidirectional iterator by a fixed offset, you have to either increment it repeatedly, or use `std::next` or `std::advance`.

Comment: @juanchopanza "The standard library doesn't like" - now that seems to be the point, if you have some source of this information. Otherwise the answer is just "it doesn't, and we don't know why". Your answer, as it is now, somehow implies that O(N) operations are inherently unsuitable for operator overloading.

Comment: Actually that is often used point against operator overloading that some tend to hide the costs with it.

Comment: @BartoszKP: It's never specified, but in practice all iterator operations are `O(logN)` or better.  Anything slower is provided as an overloaded function.

Comment: @BartoszKP Obviously having O(N) complexity does not make it impossible to have an operator overload. But the standard library is quite consistent in not providing expensive operators for iterators.

Comment: @ÖöTiib, and MooingDuck Not sure why operator call should hide the cost better than a function call :o  I understand that it is a common practice. The problem is just, that this answer doesn't explain that.

Comment: @juanchopanza ^ + I understand that, and this is interesting. However your answer doesn't explain that. Perhaps we understand the question differently, but IMHO this is the main issue to be answered.

Comment: @BartoszKP: I think the design decision is to prevent accidental use of slow functions.  Use operators by default, and if you accidentally use something slow, you get a compiler error.  If you want to do it anyway, fall back to the function version.

Comment: @MooingDuck You assume that using "something slow" by accident is more probable with an operator than with a function. Perhaps it is a valid assumption - I don't know, and neither the answer explains that.

Comment: @BartoszKP: It's not oversights in operators vs functions, it's that people should be using operators by default.  Since they do that, we can take advantage of this by not making slow operators, which means the programmer must consciously switch to standalone functions to do something slow. If someone is using functions by default, this reasoning does not help them, but it also doesn't hinder them.

Comment: @BartoszKP People switch between container types when performance requirements change or become more clear during project. If the already existing code uses operators that are expensive with the new container then that is too silent, better is when the code does not compile and so maintainer gets alerted.

Comment: @MooingDuck Again, you don't need to explain all of this to me. I'm not here to discuss the topic, but the answer.

Comment: @ÖöTiib There can be also functions with the same name for different classes, can't see how this applies to operators only. Also, please read my previous comment.

Comment: @BartoszKP It is idiomatic to use operators with iterators because they mimic array iteration via pointers. The use of functions to modify iterators is not so idiomatic, it is rather an exception.

Comment: @juanchopanza I do know that :) Let me say this one more time: I'm not saying that what you wrote in the answer is wrong. I'm not asking for a clarification for me only. I'm just suggesting that you could improve your answer. So then I could happily remove my downvote, we could all finish this boring discussion, delete our comments, and have a nice evening... :)

Comment: @BartoszKP Typical way to find calls of expensive function is simple text search. Typical way to find usages of expensive operator is to move these to private and to recompile. On one hand I already hate that method when the code is large enough and on other hand I don't want to be enforced to do that with classes of standard library as well.

Answer (score 2):

'+' operation is only provided for *Random access iterators*. And `std::set` doesn't use *Random access iterators*.